# get Transaction object from xdr base64 string

Tags: java-sdk

I have a base64 xdr string of a transaction. How can I convert that to a transaction object, so I can sign it e.g. `transaction.sign(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. such a simple thing: `Transaction.fromEnvelopeXdr(...)`