# How to rehydrate a transaction serialized in XDR to a transaction object that can be signed and submitted, with the JavaScript sdk?

Tags: transactions, xdr

The Transaction class has a .toXDR() method, but I don't see a fromXDR method.

I want to persist transactions in XDR base64, then load them, sign them, and send them.

There is a mention of a fromXDR method in the Transaction class here:

[get Transaction object from xdr base64 string](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/get-transaction-object-from-xdr-base64-string)

but it's not in the doc: https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Transaction.html or even in the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass it directly in the constructor. This is described in the doc you linked to:

> Parameters: envelope  string | xdr.TransactionEnvelope

So do this:

```
// `transactionXDR` is a string from the person generating the transaction
const transaction = new Transaction(transactionXDR, networkPassphrase);
```

See also [the docs](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Transaction.html#getKeypairSignature) for adding a signature to a transaction sent to you from someone else.